# Scraping data from Amazon to create a product tracker code

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to write a code that will find if a product on amazon is available or not. I am trying to scrape data from Amazon and then check if the string "In stock" is part of the data I am scraping.

```
        #part of a function called check
        page = requests.get(url,headers = headers)
        #parsing the html content
        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)

        # checking availability
        xpath_availability = '//*[@id="availability"]/span/text()'
        raw_availability = doc.xpath(xpath_availability)
        print(raw_availability)
        if "Is Stock" in raw_availability:
            print('Hello')


check('https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-4-Slim-1TB-Console/dp/B071CV8CG2/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=ps4&qid=1559836554&s=videogames&sr=1-2&th=1')
```

My problem is that hello is never printed and the text Im getting is either blank or the following 
`['\n        \n            \n            In Stock.\n        \n        \n    ']`, What am I doing wrong? Also if anyone has suggestions for a better way of doing this, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the header info (based on your OS and browser info, you can check it from https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_system_name/mac-os-x/), I was able to scrape the URL using:

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/PlayStation-4-Slim-1TB-Console/dp/B071CV8CG2/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=ps4&qid=1559836554&s=videogames&sr=1-2&th=1'
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

# checking availability
xpath_availability = '//*[@id="availability"]/span/text()'
raw_availability = doc.xpath(xpath_availability)

print(raw_availability)
Output: ['\n        \n            \n    In Stock.\n        \n        \n    ']
```

Comment: That is what I was getting but now I want to check if this has the string contains "Is stock"

Comment: raw_availability is of type list: 
```for x in raw_availability:
    if 'In Stock' in x:
        print('Hello World')```